# Installing Pg Admin 4 on nginx unbutu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, nginx, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having trouble finding any documentation of how to install and configure pgadmin4 to work with nginx on ubuntu 20.04, I only managed to find tutorials for apache.

I'm very new to nginx, can you guys help with a link to some documentation or tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: @Allex_Radu what issue are you encountering because you don't need nginx for pgadmin? You can simply install locally on your system and connect to the server however you need with something like this (although in dev it is normally easier in the long run with Docker, but that's a different topic): https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/ I would probably not house access to pgadmin on a production server (i.e. example.com/pgadmin4), instead do what I bring up above with remote connections, in my opinion it is safer

Comment: Host it locally, why I haven't thought of that? Thank you for your help. The issues that I was having were that all the scripts for installing pgadmin4 were for apache2. Your solution really will work for me. Thanks

Comment: @Allex_Radu, cool glad to help! It is sometimes easier if other people have an outside look

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit like you are attempting to connect to your database on a production server, from within that server... With PgAdmin this is not needed.  You can simply install locally on your system like this:

https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu

And then just remote into the server like so:

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/connecting.html#connecting-to-a-server

I would argue that it is also a smarter approach to house the pgadmin connection locally as you do not need a visual approach to your databases in the production instance in most cases.